# Using PHP, how can I identify, (decompress if applicable), and extract the files from .tar, .gz, .tar.gz, .zip files?

Tags: php, archive, phar

I know that `\Phar` and `\PharData` exist, but I'm having some trouble with the methods they supply so far.  I'm still having to detect the mime-type / file type by whatever means, before determining which `Phar*::method()` to use in an attempt to extract the archive and do work on the files it contains.

Is there a go-to, "easy-button" class that I could include (maybe some package available via composer) that handles this at a very high level?  Or am I failing to use the `Phar` and friends properly or in need of re-RTM so far?

Basically, I want to do the following  (it's a CLI script that I control for now, so security, while important with this type of thing, is on the backburner for now):

1. Detect that a file might be an archive of some kind.
2. Validate that it *seems* to be one of the following: `.tar`, `.gz`, `.tar.gz`, or `.zip`.
3. If so, attempt to extract the archive and then parse the content of it's actual files.

Is there an "easy-button" for this that I'm unaware of, or do I need to build some logic that guesses as best it can as to what type of archive it might be, and then try to use the appropriate `Phar*` method to attempt to extract it's files and do whatever work I need to on them?

I hope that makes sense the way I wrote it.  I'm trying to avoid re-inventing the wheel for a mini-project here if someone has already figured all of this out basically.

Comment: `$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Comment: @Abdulla yeah I was looking for a high-level solution that would allow me to be lazier, so I don't have to write boilerplate code for identifying and then extracting possible archives to get at the files.  Like I said, I'm just trying to avoid re-inventing the wheel if there's some sort of "turn-key" solution for this that I could utilize and rely on.

Comment: There's the `Phar::isCompressed` function, which might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @l'L'l Hm.  Yeah I seem to have overlooked that method, but I kind of wish that was a static method that would just return true or false.  It throws an exception in the class constructor if it's not an acceptable file.  Seems like I'm missing something, but if I have to basically check if it's an acceptable file before checking if it's an acceptable file, then what am I getting out of it?

Comment: Well, according to the documentation `This method requires the php.ini setting phar.readonly to be set to 0 in order to work for Phar objects, Otherwise, a PharException will be thrown.`.

Comment: @l'L'l Well I definitely missed that little tidbit.  Thanks!

Comment: Also see [PharFileInfo::isCompressed](http://php.net/manual/en/pharfileinfo.iscompressed.php), for it maybe more appropriate depending on if you are wanting to check just an entry or the entire archive.

Answer (score 1):

So, while continuing to research this I ended up seeing my own (this) SO question in google search results, which annoys me for some reason.  So just in case someone stumbles upon this looking for a good solution, I've since found a couple by searching https://packagist.org/search/?q=archive (go figure):

Here's a few of them that seem promising.

**wapmorgan/UnifiedArchive:**

- [wapmorgan/UnifiedArchive (packagist)](https://packagist.org/packages/wapmorgan/unified-archive)
- [wapmorgan/UnifiedArchive (github source)](https://github.com/wapmorgan/UnifiedArchive)

  Features (at first glance):

  - Only has one requirement of `pear/archive_tar` (which includes a few
    more utility classes also from pear).
  - It attempts to detect the filetype for you, so it could eliminate the need to do that on your own.

**alchemy/zippy:**

- [alchemy/zippy (packagist)](https://packagist.org/packages/alchemy/zippy)
- [alchemy-fr/Zippy (github source)](https://github.com/alchemy-fr/Zippy)

  Features (at first glance):

  - Code looks to have been very well designed.
  - Seems to integrate with Laravel and `guzzle\guzzle` (the popular php http client) in some way so that might be an advantage for some.

**zetacomponents/Archive**

- [zetacomponents/Archive (packagist)](https://packagist.org/packages/zetacomponents/archive)
- [zetacomponents/Archive (github source)](https://github.com/zetacomponents/Archive)

  Features (at first glance):

  - It *seems* to be a pure php implementation?  If so that's just awesome.
  - Last updated 15 days ago, so it's the most active of the three I mentioned.
  - Seems to be maintained by an organization as opposed to a single person.
  - It has the most downloads *by far* on packagist (when searching for "archive"), and though I haven't played with it yet, that's usually a good sign.

**Disclaimer:** I have only actually tried `wapmorgan/UnifiedArchive` as of this writing, and so far it's exactly what I was looking for.

Anyway, I hope this helps anyone who might stumble upon this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need pure php and if your code is running on a linux machine, a

```
exec('uncompress [-cfv] [file...]');
```

or a

```
exec('unzip filename.zip -d destination');
```

will extract the file and make it usable for php.
Of course you need to check the extension (zip, tar, etc) in order to call the right command

Comment: Yeah I definitely want to avoid exec() or any other form of 'shelling out' for future security concerns and compatibility.  I can definitely build code to detect and extract these archives, compressed files, and compressed archives, but I was just wondering if there was already a tried-and-true solution for this that is recommended.  If it doesn't exist, maybe I'll build it and open-source it?  I often find that when I try to build something like this, I realize later there is already a better solution out there that I could have used.

Comment: :) It definitely makes sense, I hope you will find or build that solution